# php creates new session file even when $_cookie['phpsessid'] was passed to server

Tags: php, session, xampp

update:
I just realized all these files

```
tillBrowserIsOpen.php
1days.php
2days.php
```

are under one directory
but `10days.php`is inside another directory could it be the problem maybe?
and does this mean each directory has it's own dedicated COOKIE? and therefore has it's own session_file on server

---

the flow in which I run applications:

1. I run `tillBrowserIsOpen.php`
2. I close browser
3. I run `1days.php`
4. I run `2days.php`
5. run `show_cookie.php` to ensure `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` is there
6. I run `10days.php`
7. I run `show_session.php`
8. run `show_cookie.php`

expectations in each step

1. A session file is created on the server ending with ...5b and ...5b is stored in `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']`
2. because browser is closed so `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` is deleted
3. then again a new session file is created file name ending with ...aa ,and ...a is stored in `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` for 1 day
4. when I run `2days.php` because `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` was passed `session_start()` connects to ...aa file and `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` expiration date is updated for 2 days
5. now I make sure that on the client side `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` is filled with ...aa file name
6. now `10days.php` creates new session file I mean why is that? `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` was passed.shouldn't it write in the same file?and the script just doesn't update `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` so it means `$_SESSION['10days']` data won't be ever accessible cuz the file name was not saved into cookie to ensure that I run step 7 and 8
7. now `$_SESSION` doesn't contain `10days.php` data
8. `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']`] is filled with `2days.php` `session_id()`

---

`show_cookie.php`

```
    <?php
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "cookie";
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    echo "<br/>";
```

---

`show_session.php`

```
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "SESSION";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "<br/>";
```

---

`tillBrowserIsOpen.php`

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['uponBrowserClosing'] = 'uponBrowserClosing';
    
    setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), 0);
    
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "cookie";
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    echo "<br/>";
    
    echo "server";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo session_id();
```

---

`1day.php`

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['1days'] = '1days';
    
    setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time()  + (24 * 3600));
    
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "cookie";
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    echo "<br/>";
    
    echo "server";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>";
    
    echo session_id();
```

---

`2days.php`

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['2days'] = '2days';
    
    setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + (2 * (24 * 3600)));
    
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "cookie";
    print_r($_COOKIE);
    echo "<br/>";
    
    echo "server";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>";
    
    echo session_id();
```

---

`10days.php`

```
        <?php
        
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['10days'] = '10days';
        
        setcookie(session_name(), session_id(), time() + (10 * (24 * 3600)));
        
        
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "cookie";
        print_r($_COOKIE);
        echo "<br/>";
        
        echo "server";
        print_r($_SESSION);
        echo "</pre>";
        
        echo session_id();
```

I expected 10days script to reuse `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']` not create new session file

Comment: _"and does this mean each directory has it's own dedicated COOKIE?"_ - have you not read the manual for the function? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php: _"path:
The path on the server in which the cookie will be available on. If set to '/', the cookie will be available within the entire domain. If set to '/foo/', the cookie will only be available within the /foo/ directory and all sub-directories such as /foo/bar/ of domain. **The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.**"_

Comment: Why are you using setcookie in the first place? `session_start` itself will already set the session cookie. And if you want to change the cookie parameters it uses, and can't do that directly via the PHP configuration, there's `session_set_cookie_params` for that.

Comment: tnx man I did'nt know about any of these

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).